# Jquery Dynamic Form Elements - Problem

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic

I've looked through the Related Questions section and I can't find an answer to this. I'm using PHP + Jquery. I added `<input type='file' name='file[]' size='20 />'` dynamically, using Jquery. However, when I Post the data, and use `print_r($_POST);`, I get the other elements that were there before I dynamically added the Jquery Code, but not the file elements.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] Code added:

```
$(".btn_add").click(function () {
$("#file_stage").before("<tr><td>Primary <input type='radio' name='primary' value='0' /></td><td>File: <input type='file' name='file[]' size='20' /></td></tr>");
```

});

[EDIT] Link to Fixee: http://fixee.org/paste/uox0hqy/

Comment: can you show us your javascript/jQuery code?

Comment: Can we see the code? Or even better; a link to a working example? Debugging code you can't see is tricky :]

Comment: I'll add the code to the main part.

Comment: What kind of element is `#file_stage`? You're adding a table row before it. Is that row landing in a table?

Comment: I'll add the code in pastebin and you can take a better look. It's this: <tr id="file_stage"></tr>

Answer (score 2):

did you used an enctype while creating the form?

```
<form action="http://example.com/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <!-- your input fields -->
</form>
```

please note that you can access files from forms via $_FILES not via $_POST

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

EDIT (code recieved): you should add the enctype to the html form using *input="file"* fields (http://fixee.org/paste/uox0hqy/ - line 80)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/content/albums/" id="new_album" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="new_album">
```

Comment: I added the enctype, however, my predicament hasn't changed. I've also tried $_FILES, as you suggested. I just get an array(), nothing else.

Comment: alright seems like trial and error doens't work here. can you post all the html/js code?

Comment: I did in the main question. I'll do a pastebin as well.

Comment: I did what you requested, but no dice. I have a question though. When I check the page source, I don't see the html code for the input file. However, I see the html file upload element, that is, when I view it in my browser. Why? Thanks.

Comment: depends on your browser. I recommend using Firefox and Firebug (Addon)

Comment: In addition it seems like you're using a framework. Some frameworks clean gobal vars like POST and FILES. You may check the frameworks manual about this.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter, plus I use Firefox. Sigh, I'll keep working on it, I'll see what happens. I'll try to report it when I find the answer.

Comment: When using codeigniter i highly recommend using the file upload class http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html